# Curl as determinant: technically appropriate?

Tags: determinant, vector-analysis

I have seen (not on the most prestigious sources) the curl of a function defined thusly:

> If $\vec{F}$ is a trivariate vector-valued function of $x$, of $y$ and of $z$ that takes the form $\vec F = a\hat x +b\hat y + c\hat z$ then the curl of the function $\nabla\times\vec{F}$ equals
>   $$\left|
> \begin{array} \\
> \hat x & \hat y & \hat z \\
> \partial\over\partial x & \partial\over\partial y & \partial\over\partial z \\
> a & b & c \\
> \end{array}
> \right|$$

I wonder if this is technically correct, because the definition of a determinant hinges on multiplication. For example, $\displaystyle \left| \begin{array} \\ A & B \\ C & D \\ \end{array} \right|$ is defined to equal $AD-BC$, which is of course equivalent to $DA-CB$. By contrast, a differential operator is not a multiplicand/multiplier, and $\displaystyle{{\partial\over\partial x}b} = \displaystyle{\partial b\over\partial x}$ does not carry the same meaning as $\displaystyle{b{\partial\over\partial x}}$.

So, **since a (partial) differential operation is not the same as multiplication, is this determinant definition of the curl of a function technically correct?**

Comment: It is treated as a $3\times 3$ matrix (not a $2 \times 2$ one). The determinant of a $3 \times 3$ operator is a more complex expression of its 9 elements. You're right it is a bit loose with the notation of partial differential operators, but in this case $b \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ is treated as $\frac{\partial b}{\partial x}$.

Comment: Here is [a link](https://math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/vcalc/deter/deter.html) describing how to find determinants of a $3 \times 3$  matrix.

Comment: Thank you, @PaulAljabar ; I was just showing a $2\times 2$ to save room.

Comment: One can force an order of multiplication where an element from an upper row goes to the left of a lower row, giving terms like $\hat x \frac{\partial}{\partial y} c$.

Comment: This notation relies on the silent convention that the "factors" must be written from left to right as you go from the top to the bottom row. E.g. $\hat x\frac\partial{\partial z}b$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes, md2perpe concurs with you on that one :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's best to view the determinant as a [*mnemonic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mnemonic) for the cross product formula rather than a *definition*, i.e., as some kind of literal determinant involving vectors, differential operators, and component functions.

Comment: Might I add that the symbol $\nabla \times $ to mean the curl is merely a notation due to Gibbs. Source: C.T.Tai, A Survey on the improper use of  $\nabla$ in vector analysis, (http://www.eecs.umich.edu/radlab/html/techreports/RL909.pdf)

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Ah, wonderful find. My question exactly is addressed in section 2.20, although the author doesn't leave much explanation as to why this is an improper use of $\nabla$ (and by that, I mean no explanation). I have to say that it is helpful to read through his comments—when he happens to make any. Do you know if any similar materials that might more explicitly explain what $\nabla$ really is? I remember having to re-teach myself that $d \over dx$ is *not* a tiny change in [something] per tiny change in $x$ but rather a shorthand for a limit—a true operator just like $\lim$ itself.

Comment: @user56478: I think that the survey is only a satellite to a main paper ("A historical study of vector analysis"). You might want to look into that. Riemannian geometry might also help, since in that context one develops a full differential calculus without coordinates. I like very much the presentation given in the first two chapters of Wald's book on general relativity.

Comment: @user56478: The "right" way to do vector calculus is with [differential forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form), as in Spivak's _Calculus on Manifolds_. The gradient, curl, and divergence operators are all manifestations on the [exterior derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative) together with identifications coming from the Euclidean dot product: [musical isomorphisms and the Hodge $*$-operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative#Invariant_formulations_of_grad.2C_curl.2C_div.2C_and_Laplacian).